# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - In Angular 4

Tags: angular

DataService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  result:any;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  getPrices() {
    return 
     this._http.get('https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/')
      .map(result => this.result = result);
  }
}
```

AppComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  objectKeys = Object.keys;
  cryptos: any;

  constructor(private _data: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.getPrices()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.cryptos = res;
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

}
```

I'm getting - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Error when i try to access this Rest API url.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned API `https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/data/coinlist/` does not support Cross Origin access. You cannot access it from a different domain than there's.

Read more at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

As an alternative you can have your server fetch the data from them.

Answer (score 0):

In StartUp.cs file of API Project

```
 ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) add below code
  services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("hereaddangularprojecturl"));
            });


and then Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
add below line of code

 app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

Comment: Please, explain your code and why is a solution to the answer. Do not limit to copy code as an answer.